# Return value of a find function searching through a vector of unique_ptr's

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, unique-ptr

I am searching through a vector of unique_ptr's to an object.  The object is resolved, for instance, by a user entering a name.  Hence a function of the sort:

```
std::unique_ptr<obj> const& objectForName(std::string name) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<obj>>::iterator it;
    it = std::find_if(objVec.begin(), objVec.end(), [name](const std::unique_ptr<obj>& object) -> bool {return object->getName() == name; });
    if (it != objVec.end())
      return *it;
    else
      throw(Some_Exception("Exception message"));
}
```

I would like to reuse this function in the case when adding an object to this vector.  Function should call this and in the case of not finding it return something that can be checked by the calling function, instead of throwing an exception.  The calling function can throw the exception on checking the return value.  My question is what can be returned that calling function can be checked?

Comment: As it seems that `object` cannot own `nullptr`, you may return `obj*` instead, and so returning `nullptr` when not found.

Answer (score 7):

Just return a pointer:

```
obj const* objectForName( std::string const& name )
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<obj>>::iterator results
            = std::find_if(
                objVec.begin(),
                objVec.end(),
                [&]( std::unique_ptr<obj> const& object ) {
                            return object->getName == name; } );
    return results != objVec.end()
        ? results->get()
        : nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Okay, but on returning a raw pointer:  Isn't this working a bit against the paradigm of smart pointers?

Comment: @worker11811 non-owning raw pointers are not discouraged. Caller does not take ownership of pointee object, so it's fine.

Comment: And if a delete is called on the object?

Comment: If your head hurts when you bang it against the wall, stop banging your head against the wall and it will stop hurting. Using `delete` is exactly what is against "the paradigm of smart pointers", not this.

Comment: I know that.  Point is I know that.  Someone else that uses the code after me sees a raw pointer and deletes it.  So isn't the point of using a raw pointer again part of the problem smart pointers are trying to fix?

Comment: @worker11811 What paradigm of smart pointers?  Smart pointers are useful and convenient in certain precise situations, but only then; you certainly don't want to use them everywhere.

Comment: @worker11811 If you have colleagues that randomly delete pointers, there's not much you can do.  What's to prevent them from deleting a reference, for example?

Comment: What are these certain precise situations?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here then.  Isn't the point of smart pointers to prevent resource leaks - let's say in cases of throwing exceptions, etc.  And especially in the case of unique_ptr's the idea of ownership.  
I'm asking this to understand something I might have missed.  But it feels a bit counter-intuitive to use a unique_ptr and then use a raw pointer on it.  How are you going to delete a `std::unique_ptr<obj> const&` reference?

Comment: @worker11811 The certain precise situations are simply those where the smart pointer semantics correspond to what is needed.  This isn't very often the case.  For example, I've never encountered a case where a vector of unique_ptr would be appropriate; usually, a vector of objects would be preferable.  But if you have a vector of unique_ptr, the _only_ thing you want to see coming out of it are references or pointers to what the unique_ptr points to; client code shouldn't be bound to what is an internal detail of your implementation.

Comment: @JamesKanze "...a vector of objects would be preferable."  Is that a vector of objects or a vector of pointers to objects?  Because then I don't see a difference between that and a vector of `unique_ptr`'s; except that the `unique_ptr` will be safer than a pointer.

Comment: @worker11811 A vector of objects.  Why the pointers?  (Normally, when you have a vector of pointers, it's because the objects have identity and cannot be copied.  And live elsewhere, so you _don't_ want `std::unique_ptr`.  While I use `std::unique_ptr` extensively as a local variable, I've not found any use for it other than as a local variable.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use something like `boost::optional` here:

```
boost::optional<std::unique_ptr<obj> const&> objectForName(std::string name);
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<obj>>::iterator it;
    it = std::find_if(objVec.begin(), objVec.end(), [name](const std::unique_ptr<obj>& object) -> bool {return object->getName() == name; });
    if (it != objVec.end())
      return *it;
    else
      return boost::none;
}
```

Usage:

```
const auto val = objectForName("bla1");
if (val) std::cout << "ok: " << val.get()->getName();
else std::cout << "none";
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.  Any ideas on how to do it without using the boost library?  I'd prefer to do it using the standard library.

Comment: @worker11811 gcc 4.9 and clang has `experimental/optional` header. I think it is nearly the same as boost. But it's an experimental extension. Maybe, you can just copy-paste it to you project, it's not so much code there..

Comment: So we should use `boost::optional` with a reference, rather than a pointer.  This sounds like extra complexity for nothing.  (Many, many years back, I considered extending my `Fallible` class to support instantiation over reference types, and decided that it was stupid, since all it would do would be to wrap a pointer.  In the case of `boost::optional`, it's even more stupid, because the interface of `boost::optional` is designed to mimic that of a pointer.  The documentation of `boost::optional` says it, in fact: the "standard" optional type is a pointer.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Well, this is the original code with minimal modifications. Maybe there is some big idea, why this function returns a unique_ptr reference (for example it uses unique_ptr's `get_deleter`). If it is only used as a reference to object, then I agree, returning a pointer looks better.